# Yik yak navigation disappear effect?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Does anyone know how to make the navigation bar fade away as you scroll down the feed just like in the app Yik Yak? It also reappears wherever you are at when you start to scroll back up the feed. Also I would like to know how to be able to implement this using swift language

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this quite easily with UIKit. You need to do the following

1. Listen to the scroll view delegate callbacks. Its methods will inform you when a scroll occurred, when it starts and finishes, etc. You can check the `contentOffset` of the scroll view there and decide if you need to hide or show the navigation bar.
2. You can then call the view controllers `navigationController`'s method `setNavigationBarHidden(animated:)` to show and hide with the standard animation.